# pgfplots: Add/subtract whole columns of data files with one another?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to analyze data files with the following format

```
0.01    1.00    11.00    21.00
0.02    2.00    12.00    22.00
0.03    3.00    13.00    23.00
0.04    4.00    14.00    24.00
0.05    5.00    15.00    25.00
```

I want to create a plot with `pgfplots` that uses the first column as the x-values. The y-values shall be obtained by adding several of the other columns to one another or subtract one from the other - a little bit like a spreadsheet application could do it. How can this be achieved with `pgfplots`? 
And if it is possible, is it easy to do the same with lines instead of columns or perform other simple mathematical calculations (multiplication, taking the logarithm, etc.)?

Comment: You can use pgfplotstable to read your data and create new colums that contain your math results. There is a large section ans examples available in the documentation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `\addplot table [y expr=...] {<inline table or table macro>};` to specify what to plot. If your columns have names, you can access them in `y expr` using `\thisrow{<column name>}`. If you want to use the column index, use `\thisrowno{<column number>}`. To only have to load the table once instead of supplying it to each plot, use the `\pgfplotstableread{<table contents>}<\tablemacro>` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    1.00    11.00    21.00
0.02    2.00    12.00    22.00
0.03    3.00    13.00    23.00
0.04    4.00    14.00    24.00
0.05    5.00    15.00    25.00
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=60]
\addplot table [y expr=\thisrowno{1} + \thisrowno{2} + \thisrowno{3}] {\datatable}; \addlegendentry{$1 + 2 + 3$}
\addplot table [y expr=\thisrowno{2} - \thisrowno{1}] {\datatable}; \addlegendentry{$2-1$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```