# real number of my files at tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots

I have a tikzpicture that read 3 data files. The values at Y axis are converted automatically to x10^5. I need to show the exact number of my data files. How do I do that?

Thanks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Comparação do armazenamento do UiSCSI x Samba}
        xmajorgrids=true,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        xmin=0,ymin=0,
        ytick={0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,120000,140000,160000},
        xlabel={Quantidade copiada em GigaBytes},
        ylabel={Tempo em segundos},
        legend style={legend pos=north west}]
    \addplot table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {metricas/data01.dat};
    \addlegendentry{UiSCSI}
    \addplot table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {metricas/data02.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Ustore}
    \addplot table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {metricas/data03.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Samba}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `scaled y ticks=false`

Comment: it worked, thanks. I wonder other thing, if my numbers are in seconds and I want to convert it to hours, minutes and seconds inside the tikzpicture. Is that possible? thanks again

Comment: Could you please make your snippet fully compilable and add portions of the data files? Let people have some fun over your question. I believe that you are looking for `y expr` from the `pgfplots` reference manual. Anyway, your additional question is probably worth another question at TeX.SX as the result must be formatted to a suitable format. A tip (computational part): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41033/pgfplots-add-subtract-whole-columns-of-data-files-with-one-another

Comment: `y filter/.code` is probably another approach (computational part), please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/strange-interaction-between-addlegendentry-and-y-filter-in-pgfplot or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134730/how-to-scale-existing-coordinates-data-in-pgfplots

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.