# Trying to draw 4 lines plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to get whats on the screenshot:

[image]

This is the closest I could get:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
    %\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

    \usepackage{tikz}

    \decimalpoint

    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

    \pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
        \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
        inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=orange] {};
    }

    \begin{document}



    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
    \definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0}

    \begin{axis}[
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={draw=white!80.0!black},
    tick align=outside,
    tick pos=left,
    x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
    xmin=-1.15, xmax=2.15,
    xtick style={color=black},
    y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
    ymin=-2.8805745743823, ymax=0.842878507835834,
    ytick style={color=black}
    ]
    \path [fill=color0, fill opacity=0.1]
    (axis cs:-1,-1.48851962372964)
    --(axis cs:-1,-0.325560219466025)
    --(axis cs:-0.99,-0.344916678779826)
    --(axis cs:-0.98,-0.361970145476152)
    --(axis cs:-0.97,-0.376516944637396)
    --(axis cs:-0.96,-0.388350537220021)
    --(axis cs:-0.95,-0.397267994151541)
    --(axis cs:-0.94,-0.403079197839339)
    --(axis cs:-0.93,-0.40561892880781)
    --(axis cs:-0.92,-0.404761428801433)
    --(axis cs:-0.91,-0.40043621405791)
    --(axis cs:-0.9,-0.39264303010705)
    --(axis cs:-0.89,-0.381463197781045)
    --(axis cs:-0.88,-0.367063317348322)
    --(axis cs:-0.87,-0.349687660515876)
    --(axis cs:-0.86,-0.329642457143275)
    --(axis cs:-0.85,-0.307276062493656)
    --(axis cs:-0.84,-0.282958192412817)
    --(axis cs:-0.83,-0.257061001762888)
    --(axis cs:-0.82,-0.229943792452013)
    --(axis cs:-0.81,-0.201942009908898)
    --(axis cs:-0.8,-0.173360298495605)
    --(axis cs:-0.79,-0.144468881519921)
    --(axis cs:-0.78,-0.115502369690069)
    --(axis cs:-0.77,-0.086660162813515)
    --(axis cs:-0.76,-0.0581077745964513)
    --(axis cs:-0.75,-0.0299785976410224)
    --(axis cs:-0.74,-0.0023757924957552)
    --(axis cs:-0.73,0.0246258838135547)
    --(axis cs:-0.72,0.0509783969993703)
    --(axis cs:-0.71,0.0766589189474857)
    --(axis cs:-0.7,0.101668438393112)
    --(axis cs:-0.69,0.126030417188297)
    --(axis cs:-0.68,0.149789367877619)
    --(axis cs:-0.67,0.173009183448994)
    --(axis cs:-0.66,0.195771002252518)
    --(axis cs:-0.65,0.218170344580013)
    --(axis cs:-0.64,0.240313224255155)
    --(axis cs:-0.63,0.262310940695851)
    --(axis cs:-0.62,0.284273325987213)
    --(axis cs:-0.61,0.306300393022326)
    --(axis cs:-0.6,0.328472627672117)
    --(axis cs:-0.59,0.350840574143136)
    --(axis cs:-0.58,0.373414797606605)
    --(axis cs:-0.57,0.396157935804781)
    --(axis cs:-0.56,0.418982625657244)
    --(axis cs:-0.55,0.441756895779896)
    --(axis cs:-0.54,0.464313792346684)
    --(axis cs:-0.53,0.486463065244078)
    --(axis cs:-0.52,0.508003410840526)
    --(axis cs:-0.51,0.52873397085101)
    --(axis cs:-0.5,0.548464193625829)
    --(axis cs:-0.49,0.567021633128266)
    --(axis cs:-0.48,0.584257654311303)
    --(axis cs:-0.47,0.60005126707999)
    --(axis cs:-0.46,0.614311423615695)
    --(axis cs:-0.45,0.626978118307294)
    --(axis cs:-0.44,0.638022565626321)
    --(axis cs:-0.429999999999999,0.647446630631934)
    --(axis cs:-0.419999999999999,0.655281569229535)
    --(axis cs:-0.409999999999999,0.661586011855572)
    --(axis cs:-0.399999999999999,0.666443003756222)
    --(axis cs:-0.389999999999999,0.66995581223263)
    --(axis cs:-0.379999999999999,0.672242155298317)
    --(axis cs:-0.369999999999999,0.673426545610457)
    --(axis cs:-0.359999999999999,0.673630640462282)
    --(axis cs:-0.349999999999999,0.672961892543437)
    --(axis cs:-0.339999999999999,0.671501666287816)
    --(axis cs:-0.329999999999999,0.669297151582184)
    --(axis cs:-0.319999999999999,0.666360694361955)
    --(axis cs:-0.309999999999999,0.662673144356181)
    --(axis cs:-0.299999999999999,0.658189261532723)
    --(axis cs:-0.289999999999999,0.652844428575926)
    --(axis cs:-0.279999999999999,0.646561760188481)
    --(axis cs:-0.269999999999999,0.639258736020022)
    --(axis cs:-0.259999999999999,0.630852734747249)
    --(axis cs:-0.249999999999999,0.621265205366631)
    --(axis cs:-0.239999999999999,0.610424559694992)
    --(axis cs:-0.229999999999999,0.59826812788143)
    --(axis cs:-0.219999999999999,0.584743942726682)
    --(axis cs:-0.209999999999999,0.569813960568898)
    --(axis cs:-0.199999999999999,0.553458271333268)
    --(axis cs:-0.189999999999999,0.535678932857971)
    --(axis cs:-0.179999999999999,0.516503093469665)
    --(axis cs:-0.169999999999999,0.495985293799417)
    --(axis cs:-0.159999999999999,0.474208899588321)
    --(axis cs:-0.149999999999999,0.451286632370334)
    --(axis cs:-0.139999999999999,0.427360149577989)
    --(axis cs:-0.129999999999999,0.402598597020283)
    --(axis cs:-0.119999999999999,0.377196032064979)
    --(axis cs:-0.109999999999999,0.351367611758961)
    --(axis cs:-0.0999999999999992,0.325344471223833)
    --(axis cs:-0.0899999999999992,0.299367294035265)
    --(axis cs:-0.0799999999999992,0.273678698755592)
    --(axis cs:-0.0699999999999992,0.248514721054936)
    --(axis cs:-0.0599999999999992,0.224095829455429)
    --(axis cs:-0.0499999999999992,0.20061803321986)
    --(axis cs:-0.0399999999999991,0.178244681783128)
    --(axis cs:-0.0299999999999991,0.157099523750401)
    --(axis cs:-0.0199999999999991,0.137262647201024)
    --(axis cs:-0.00999999999999912,0.118772252206627)
    --(axis cs:8.88178419700125e-16,0.101629768619645)
    --(axis cs:0.0100000000000009,0.0858057301515805)
    --(axis cs:0.0200000000000009,0.0712457386686163)
    --(axis cs:0.0300000000000009,0.0578761017737583)
    --(axis cs:0.0400000000000009,0.045608877895088)
    --(axis cs:0.0500000000000009,0.0343462001630316)
    --(axis cs:0.0600000000000009,0.0239838556351616)
    --(axis cs:0.070000000000001,0.0144141658196533)
    --(axis cs:0.080000000000001,0.00552825239254651)
    --(axis cs:0.090000000000001,-0.00278221348534136)
    --(axis cs:0.100000000000001,-0.010623680565864)
    --(axis cs:0.110000000000001,-0.0180997171309547)
    --(axis cs:0.120000000000001,-0.0253102652166324)
    --(axis cs:0.130000000000001,-0.0323510873791958)
    --(axis cs:0.140000000000001,-0.0393133564922624)
    --(axis cs:0.150000000000001,-0.0462833498710045)
    --(axis cs:0.160000000000001,-0.0533422178776493)
    --(axis cs:0.170000000000001,-0.0605658041711227)
    --(axis cs:0.180000000000001,-0.068024500155482)
    --(axis cs:0.190000000000001,-0.0757831202264155)
    --(axis cs:0.200000000000001,-0.0839007873728289)
    --(axis cs:0.210000000000001,-0.0924308207837298)
    --(axis cs:0.220000000000001,-0.101420618521141)
    --(axis cs:0.230000000000001,-0.110911529184345)
    --(axis cs:0.240000000000001,-0.120938706914506)
    --(axis cs:0.250000000000001,-0.13153094413429)
    --(axis cs:0.260000000000001,-0.142710476132162)
    --(axis cs:0.270000000000001,-0.154492750998399)
    --(axis cs:0.280000000000001,-0.166886157499885)
    --(axis cs:0.290000000000001,-0.179891702227789)
    --(axis cs:0.300000000000001,-0.193502625731172)
    --(axis cs:0.310000000000001,-0.207703945328966)
    --(axis cs:0.320000000000001,-0.222471909831406)
    --(axis cs:0.330000000000001,-0.237773348485427)
    --(axis cs:-0.96,-1.33720025911546)
    --(axis cs:-0.97,-1.37416266546194)
    --(axis cs:-0.98,-1.41182425199202)
    --(axis cs:-0.99,-1.45000176760694)
    --(axis cs:-1,-1.48851962372964)
    --cycle;

    \addplot [color1, dashed]
    table {%
    -1 -1.55887999194013
    -0.99 -1.50234817104885
    -0.98 -1.44617001527823
    -0.97 -1.39037205297874
    -0.96 -1.33498065033889
    -0.95 -1.28002198765746
    -0.94 -1.22552203578295
    -0.93 -1.17150653274161
    -0.92 -1.11800096057494
    -0.91 -1.06503052240758
    -0.9 -1.01262011976617
    -0.89 -0.960794330169693
    -0.88 -0.909577385011351
    -0.87 -0.858993147751946
    -0.86 -0.809065092444378
    -0.85 -0.759816282608583
    -0.84 -0.711269350475917
    -0.83 -0.663446476621684
    -0.82 -0.616369370004107
    -0.81 -0.570059248427734
    -0.8 -0.524536819448848
    -0.79 -0.479822261740061
    -0.78 -0.435935206930873
    -0.77 -0.392894721940528
    -0.76 -0.350719291819077
    -0.75 -0.309426803112078
    -0.74 -0.269034527763912
    -0.73 -0.229559107574203
    -0.72 -0.191016539221316
    -0.71 -0.153422159866429
    -0.7 -0.116790633351125
    -0.69 -0.081135937000921
    -0.68 -0.0464713490466193
    -0.67 -0.0128094366747979
    -0.66 0.0198379552818108
    -0.65 0.0514597150038704
    -0.64 0.082045473685326
    -0.63 0.111585614864631
    -0.62 0.140071283078915
    -0.61 0.167494391833299
    -0.6 0.193847630878196
    -0.59 0.219124472788046
    -0.58 0.243319178835554
    -0.57 0.266426804156159
    -0.56 0.288443202198077
    -0.55 0.30936502845392
    -0.54 0.329189743470525
    -0.53 0.347915615134292
    -0.52 0.365541720229967
    -0.51 0.382067945271477
    -0.5 0.397494986604055
    -0.49 0.411824349777582
    -0.48 0.425058348191687
    -0.47 0.437200101013851
    -0.46 0.44825353037236
    -0.45 0.45822335782666
    -0.44 0.467115100118266
    -0.429999999999999 0.474935064206073
    -0.419999999999999 0.481690341590516
    -0.409999999999999 0.487388801931698
    -0.399999999999999 0.492039085967227
    -0.389999999999999 0.495650597736136
    -0.379999999999999 0.498233496115883
    -0.369999999999999 0.499798685680048
    -0.359999999999999 0.500357806884947
    -0.349999999999999 0.499923225594017
    -0.339999999999999 0.498508021949363
  0.740000000000002 -0.826165472236085
    0.750000000000002 -0.81557319688792
    0.760000000000002 -0.80448070818092
    0.770000000000002 -0.792905278059469
    0.780000000000002 -0.780864793069124
    0.790000000000002 -0.768377738259936
    0.800000000000002 -0.755463180551149
    0.810000000000002 -0.742140751572263
    0.820000000000002 -0.72843062999589
    0.830000000000002 -0.714353523378313
    0.840000000000002 -0.699930649524079
    0.850000000000002 -0.685183717391414
    0.860000000000002 -0.670134907555619
    0.870000000000002 -0.654806852248051
    0.880000000000002 -0.639222614988646
    0.890000000000002 -0.623405669830304
    0.900000000000002 -0.607379880233827
    0.910000000000002 -0.591169477592417
    0.920000000000002 -0.574799039425053
    0.930000000000002 -0.558293467258387
    0.940000000000002 -0.541677964217051
    0.950000000000002 -0.524978012342542
    0.960000000000002 -0.508219349661108
    0.970000000000002 -0.491427947021261
    0.980000000000002 -0.474629984721768
    0.990000000000002 -0.457851828951143
    1 -0.441120008059864
    1.01 -0.424461188686647
    1.02 -0.407902151760266
    1.03 -0.391469768398531
    1.04 -0.375190975726093
    1.05 -0.359092752632849
    1.06 -0.343202095494762
    1.07 -0.327545993878949
    1.08 -0.312151406254889
    1.09 -0.297045235733618
    1.1 -0.282254305856749
    1.11 -0.267805336457094
    1.12 -0.253724919612618
    1.13 -0.240039495715361
    1.14 -0.226775329676873
    1.15 -0.213958487291568
    1.16 -0.201614811779263
    1.17 -0.18976990052803
    1.18 -0.178449082058267
    1.19 -0.167677393228752
    1.2 -0.157479556705146
    1.21 -0.147879958711271
    1.22 -0.138902627083154
    1.23 -0.130571209645592
    1.24 -0.122908952930712
    1.25 -0.115938681257655
    1.26 -0.109682776192235
    1.27 -0.104163156405036
    1.28 -0.0994012579460903
    1.29 -0.0954180149538801
    1.3 -0.0922338408160256
    1.31 -0.0898686097986136
    1.32 -0.0883416391607003
    1.33 -0.0876716717700813
    1.34 -0.0878768592359759
    1.35 -0.0889747455738054
    1.36 -0.0909822514167601
    1.37 -0.093915658788375
    1.38 -0.0977905964498066
    1.39 -0.102622025835
    1.4 -0.108424227586413
    1.41 -0.115210788703399
    1.42 -0.122994590314824
    1.43 -0.131787796086922
    1.44 -0.141601841276814
    1.45 -0.152447422441553
    1.46 -0.164334487811939
    1.47 -0.177272228339787
    1.48 -0.191269069426687
    1.49 -0.206332663341715
    1.5 -0.222469882334907
    1.51 -0.239686812452694
    1.52 -0.257988748060874
    1.53 -0.277380187080041
    1.54 -0.29786482693776
    1.55 -0.319445561241126
    1.56 -0.342124477172722
    1.57 -0.365902853612287
    1.58 -0.39078115998582
    1.59 -0.416759055843119
    1.6 -0.443835391164166
    1.61 -0.472008207394071
    1.62 -0.501274739205637
    1.63 -0.531631416987966
    1.64 -0.563073870058869
    1.65 -0.595596930598187
    1.66 -0.629194638298478
    1.67 -0.663860245728891
    1.68 -0.6995862244074
    1.69 -0.736364271575929
    1.7 -0.774185317672277
    1.71 -0.813039534492103
    1.72 -0.852916344033655
    1.73 -0.893804428017255
    1.74 -0.935691738070988
    1.75 -0.97856550657342
    1.76 -1.02241225814359
    1.77 -1.06721782176797
    1.78 -1.11296734355339
    1.79 -1.15964530009455
    1.8 -1.20723551244402
    1.81 -1.25572116067226
    1.82 -1.30508479900436
    1.83 -1.35530837152005
    1.84 -1.40637322840289
    1.85 -1.45826014272375
    1.86 -1.51094932774383
    1.87 -1.56442045472133
    1.88 -1.61865267120597
    1.89 -1.6736246198048
    1.9 -1.72931445740238
    1.91 -1.78569987481814
    1.92 -1.84275811688311
    1.93 -1.90046600291808
    1.94 -1.95879994759458
    1.95 -2.01773598216016
    1.96 -2.07724977600856
    1.97 -2.13731665857571
    1.98 -2.19791164154151
    1.99 -2.25900944131764
    };
    \addlegendentry{Noise-free objective}
    \addplot [blue]
    table {%
    -1 -0.907039921597832
    -0.99 -0.897459223193385
    -0.98 -0.886897198734088
    -0.97 -0.875339805049666
    -0.96 -0.862775398167738
    -0.95 -0.849195025309267
    -0.94 -0.834592739488229
    -0.93 -0.818965938179111
    -0.92 -0.802315727601792
    -0.91 -0.784647314263667
    -0.9 -0.765970425494556
    -0.89 -0.746299752578021
    -0.88 -0.725655212523403
    -0.87 -0.704061700088285
    -0.86 -0.681548658123561
    -0.85 -0.658149669877288
    -0.84 -0.633902079331194
    -0.83 -0.608846637507697
    -0.82 -0.583027172774929
    -0.81 -0.556490283260501
    -0.8 -0.52928504956185
    -0.79 -0.501462766011975
    -0.78 -0.473076688824579
    -0.77 -0.444181799502333
    -0.76 -0.414834581945884
    -0.75 -0.385092811750266
    -0.74 -0.355015356218782
    -0.73 -0.32466198366304
    -0.72 -0.294093180591432
    -0.71 -0.263369975416945
    -0.7 -0.232553767339208
    -0.69 -0.201706159074839
    -0.68 -0.170888792124607
    -0.67 -0.140163183275935
    -0.66 -0.109590561044477
    -0.65 -0.0792317007592054
    -0.64 -0.049146756991636
    -0.63 -0.0193950920212984
    -0.62 0.00996490098350655
    -0.61 0.0388759814083581
    -0.6 0.0672822526198242
    -0.59 0.0951293627653644
    -0.58 0.122364716630198
    -0.57 0.148937775044452
    -0.56 0.174800669295566
    -0.55 0.199908370732665
    -0.54 0.224218393171054
    -0.53 0.247690479642886
    -0.52 0.270286305726264
    -0.51 0.291969198460951
    -0.5 0.312703869913104
    -0.49 0.332456164504068
    -0.48 0.351192819268269
    -0.47 0.368881236253586
    -0.46 0.38548926632326
    -0.45 0.400985003662704
    -0.44 0.415336590336736
    -0.429999999999999 0.428512030283327
    -0.419999999999999 0.440479012169073
    -0.409999999999999 0.451204740569121
    -0.399999999999999 0.460655774970517
    -0.389999999999999 0.468797876133051
    -0.379999999999999 0.475595859375428
    -0.369999999999999 0.481013454387616
    -0.359999999999999 0.485013171202027
    -0.349999999999999 0.487556172098653
    -0.339999999999999 0.488602151386953
    -0.329999999999999 0.488109411032886
    -0.319999999999999 0.486035791942374
    -0.309999999999999 0.482340082272474
    -0.299999999999999 0.476983466963979
    -0.289999999999999 0.469931001455878
    -0.279999999999999 0.461153116614478
    -0.269999999999999 0.450627162020069
    -0.259999999999999 0.438338994886488
    -0.249999999999999 0.424284622043595
    -0.239999999999999 0.408471902590584
    -0.229999999999999 0.390922315526796
    -0.219999999999999 0.371672456248522
    -0.209999999999999 0.350773837239803
    -0.199999999999999 0.328291420260904
    -0.189999999999999 0.304302089303548
    -0.179999999999999 0.278893190590448
    -0.169999999999999 0.252161132445194
    -0.159999999999999 0.224210037896611
    -0.149999999999999 0.195150443055491
    -0.139999999999999 0.165098034452496
    -0.129999999999999 0.134172418655899
    -0.119999999999999 0.102495917595707
    -0.109999999999999 0.0701923831077931
    -0.0999999999999992 0.0373860242776605
    -0.0899999999999992 0.00420024120889906
    -0.0799999999999992 -0.0292435411338854
    -0.0699999999999992 -0.0628270453536928
    -0.0599999999999992 -0.0964363266835839
    -0.0499999999999992 -0.129962977082016
    -0.0399999999999991 -0.163305354817695
    -0.0299999999999991 -0.196369837403747
    -0.0199999999999991 -0.229071769951465
    -0.00999999999999912 -0.261335340061834
    8.88178419700125e-16 -0.29309293549262
    0.0100000000000009 -0.324284512103864
    0.0200000000000009 -0.354857001085186
    0.0300000000000009 -0.384763753278047
    0.0400000000000009 -0.413964018525034
    0.0500000000000009 -0.442422458091697
    0.0600000000000009 -0.470108688314642
    0.070000000000001 -0.496996853732365
    0.080000000000001 -0.523065228053191
    0.090000000000001 -0.548295841408205
    0.100000000000001 -0.572674132425617
    0.110000000000001 -0.59618862374788
    0.120000000000001 -0.618830619693608
    0.130000000000001 -0.64059392484315
    0.140000000000001 -0.661474582400405
    0.150000000000001 -0.681470631253396
    0.160000000000001 -0.700581880723294
    0.170000000000001 -0.718809702055482
    0.180000000000001 -0.736156835767742
    0.190000000000001 -0.752627214029195
    0.200000000000001 -0.768225797299907
    0.210000000000001 -0.782958424515166
    0.220000000000001 -0.796831676150136
    0.230000000000001 -0.809852749550576
    0.240000000000001 -0.82202934596331
    0.250000000000001 -0.833369568746506
    0.260000000000001 -0.843881832284479
    0.270000000000001 -0.853574781175253
    0.280000000000001 -0.862457219300951
    0.290000000000001 -0.870538048431981
    0.300000000000001 -0.877826216055732
    0.310000000000001 -0.88433067215932
    0.320000000000001 -0.890060334733738
    0.330000000000001 -0.895024063804155
    0.340000000000001 -0.899230643827586
    0.350000000000001 -0.902688774335228
    0.360000000000001 -0.905407068732528
    0.370000000000001 -0.907394061205236
    0.380000000000001 -0.908658221715116
    0.390000000000001 -0.909207979103789
    0.400000000000001 -0.909051752358473
    0.410000000000001 -0.908197990128499
    0.420000000000001 -0.906655218616903
    0.430000000000001 -0.90443209800714
    0.440000000000001 -0.901537487621206
    0.450000000000001 -0.897980520041989
    0.460000000000001 -0.89377068447024
    0.470000000000001 -0.888917919624496
    0.480000000000001 -0.883432716531281
    0.490000000000001 -0.877326231592925
    0.500000000000001 -0.870610410361305
    0.510000000000001 -0.863298122488016
    0.520000000000001 -0.855403308365228
    0.530000000000001 -0.846941138016288
    0.540000000000001 -0.837928182152364
    0.550000000000001 -0.828382551492862
    0.560000000000001 -0.818323858346747
    0.570000000000001 -0.80777306876948
    0.580000000000001 -0.796752357788224
    0.590000000000001 -0.785284976585769
    0.600000000000001 -0.773395130842342
    0.610000000000001 -0.761107869472876
    0.620000000000001 -0.748448983036786
    0.630000000000001 -0.735444911134285
    0.640000000000001 -0.722122658137901
    0.650000000000001 -0.708509716640309
    0.660000000000001 -0.69463399802976
    0.670000000000001 -0.68052376963266
    0.680000000000001 -0.666207597888938
    0.690000000000002 -0.651714297050207
    0.700000000000002 -0.637072882913084
    0.710000000000002 -0.622312531120746
    0.720000000000002 -0.607462539584671
    0.730000000000002 -0.592552294595884
    0.740000000000002 -0.577611240210593
    0.750000000000002 -0.562668850509282
    0.760000000000002 -0.54775460434087
    0.770000000000002 -0.532897962174651
    0.780000000000002 -0.518128344692395
    0.790000000000002 -0.503475112761187
    0.800000000000002 -0.488967548434441
    0.810000000000002 -0.474634836633981
    0.820000000000002 -0.460506047170154
    0.830000000000002 -0.446610116759762
    0.840000000000002 -0.432975830702965
    0.850000000000002 -0.41963180388043
    0.860000000000002 -0.406606460730826
    0.870000000000002 -0.393928013866141
    0.880000000000002 -0.381624440978475
    0.890000000000002 -0.369723459686748
    0.900000000000002 -0.358252499965152
    0.910000000000002 -0.347238673787292
    0.920000000000002 -0.336708741610619
    0.930000000000002 -0.326689075314991
    0.940000000000002 -0.31720561719708
    0.950000000000002 -0.308283834608641
    0.960000000000002 -0.299948669811512
    0.970000000000002 -0.292224484605539
    0.980000000000002 -0.285134999267234
    0.990000000000002 -0.278703225317113
    1 -0.272951391611962
    1.01 -0.267900863234859
    1.02 -0.263572052630614
    1.03 -0.259984322407117
    1.04 -0.257155879194045
    1.05 -0.255103657919262
    1.06 -0.253843195829997
    1.07 -0.253388495550449
    1.08 -0.253751876429722
    1.09 -0.254943813393802
    1.1 -0.256972762472645
    1.11 -0.259844975673987
    1.12 -0.263564392966463
    1.13 -0.268132752728607
    1.14 -0.273549779264198
    1.15 -0.279813359578244
    1.16 -0.286919706698489
    1.17 -0.294863510327367
    1.18 -0.303638075565923
    1.19 -0.313235450410166
    1.2 -0.323646542681499
    1.21 -0.334861227016098
    1.22 -0.346868442503469
    1.23 -0.3596562815316
    1.24 -0.373212070365198
    1.25 -0.387522441954329
    1.26 -0.402573401443253
    1.27 -0.41835038482336
    1.28 -0.43483831114972
    1.29 -0.452021628717866
    1.3 -0.469884355575916
    1.31 -0.488410114726951
    1.32 -0.507582164357753
    1.33 -0.527383423412309
    1.34 -0.547796492812083
    1.35 -0.568803672609747
    1.36 -0.59038697534889
    1.37 -0.612528135889091
    1.38 -0.63520861794366
    1.39 -0.658409617566271
    1.4 -0.68211206381261
    1.41 -0.706296616794
    1.42 -0.730943663331709
    1.43 -0.756033310413349
    1.44 -0.781545376646306
    1.45 -0.807459381897593
    1.46 -0.833754535304765
    1.47 -0.86040972183871
    1.48 -0.887403487596094
    1.49 -0.914714023997045
    1.5 -0.942319151062316
    1.51 -0.970196299943648
    1.52 -0.99832249488138
    1.53 -1.02667433476452
    1.54 -1.05522797447051
    1.55 -1.08395910616471
    1.56 -1.11284294074363
    1.57 -1.14185418961017
    1.58 -1.17096704697516
    1.59 -1.2001551728855
    1.6 -1.22939167718713
    1.61 -1.25864910463895
    1.62 -1.2878994214037
    1.63 -1.31711400315213
    1.64 -1.34626362502813
    1.65 -1.37531845373561
    1.66 -1.40424804202142
    1.67 -1.43302132584368
    1.68 -1.46160662453158
    1.69 -1.4899716442598
    1.7 -1.51808348518014
    1.71 -1.54590865257323
    1.72 -1.57341307240513
    1.73 -1.60056211169721
    1.74 -1.62732060414281
    1.75 -1.65365288143114
    1.76 -1.67952281076755
    1.77 -1.7048938391098
    1.78 -1.7297290446729
    1.79 -1.75399119628926
    1.8 -1.77764282124835
    1.81 -1.80064628227893
    1.82 -1.82296386437861
    1.83 -1.84455787223991
    1.84 -1.86539073906865
    1.85 -1.88542514764053
    1.86 -1.90462416449408
    1.87 -1.92295138821469
    1.88 -1.94037111282281
    1.89 -1.95684850734279
    1.9 -1.97234981269477
    1.91 -1.98684255712228
    1.92 -2.00029579144246
    1.93 -2.01268034548459
    1.94 -2.02396910716511
    1.95 -2.03413732573562
    1.96 -2.04316294083288
    1.97 -2.05102693905771
    1.98 -2.05771373991358
    1.99 -2.06321161304462
    };
    \addlegendentry{Surrogate function}
    \addplot [semithick, black, mark=x, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks]
    table {%
    -0.9 -0.825432128428033
    1.1 -0.231361279867999
    2 -2.13334200661748
    0.532590053023267 -0.866953615512358
    -0.578648048868695 0.255826240005363
    -0.584591494200069 0.0165018513475239
    -0.236565261297747 0.467802871409765
    -0.236475626946525 0.554828129885735
    -0.349930664809401 0.287304073113536
    -0.0387232480515882 -0.291594304645341
    -0.354762254411333 0.448310707175517
    -0.352462159713166 0.633281980389827
    };
    \addlegendentry{Noisy samples}
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

> I had to cut / withhold some tuples since the limit is 30k

Comment: Your own code shows that, if you have the right plots, you can produce the desired outcome. Apparently you do not have the data for the desired plot. Why do you expect anyone else has?

Comment: To expand on the comment of @Schrödinger'scat: what exactly do you want to change? Do you want to add the 4th line on the bottom? Or do you want to change the colors, thickness, line style, point style, to match your example? Or do you want to change the _values_ of the plotted lines?

Comment: @Marijn Exactly! I’d like to add the 4th line on the bottom!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I know! But sometimes it can be approximated with a function(s). Besides, I’d like to add the line on the bottom.

Comment: @Marijn Plus, I’m having trouble when I want to add f(x) and aEI on the y axis as a label and delete the values on the y axis. The same on the x-axis. I throws an error on both cases. I’m only using `ylabel` and `xlabel`

Comment: @Delan what should be the value of the aEI function? It looks like the difference between the objective and the surrogate, but not exactly?

Comment: @Marijn Yes! Exactly

Comment: Do you need to do that in `pgfplots`, can't you just prepare another dataset and plot it the same way? That said, if you can put the data in text files, then you can the technique described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41033/pgfplots-add-subtract-whole-columns-of-data-files-with-one-another